# Deleted "Deployments" file in Azure DebugConsole

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I was trying to delete the wwwroot directory in azure when I accidentally deleted the deployments directory. This wiped out my entire deployment history. Is there a way for me to retrieve this back? This is on my stage server and not production. We do swaps from stage to production then resync stage with our remote repro. I was able to resync stage to the latest deployment. However, It would be nice to be have past deployments in case we ever need to redeploy them.

Am I pretty much screwed? Are there steps to deploying a .NET Core 2 app that was migrated from .NET Core 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

**The files deleted from Kudu console cannot be recovered.**

It is recommended to use **Backup** feature available for such accident deletion.

The [Backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-backup) and [Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-restore) feature in Azure App Service lets you easily create app backups manually or automatically.

You can restore your app to a previous state, or create a new app based on one of your original app's backups.